# Alternative way to obtain h parameters without using a short circuit

Tags: network

I'm trying to answer the following question from a text:

> Sometimes the use of a short circuit leads to generator damage. Can
>   you suggest an alternative means of obtaining data to calculate the
>   ***h*** parameters without using a short circuit?

I know that to find the output impedance of a power supply we can use two resistor loads instead of shorting. How about in this case`? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXuTIJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But h parameters are a function of frequency, so the impedance ratio include reactance and generally not accurate using this method for RF, but possible for <200MHz like most good scope probes.

But ESL, ESR and stray reactance can result in errors.

Comment: but in that case R1 parameter is unknown. therefore to select R2 as 99 times R1 first you have to know R1. and R1 can be known by only shorting terminals and R1=V1/I1. isnt it? i thought with extra two known resistors R2 and R3 we could figure out R1 from two equations.

Comment: NO, you adjust R2 for 1% or 10% or in the case of CMOS examine specs Vol/Iol=ESR or (Vss-Voh)/Ioh =ESR which is standardized for every family ,but varies with voltage slightly or +/-25% worst case for 10% variation in supply.

Comment: oh okay so R2 is an adjustable resistor

Comment: yes or you get ESR from PSU % Load Reg specs or CMOS specs or transistor rCE specs or Vce(sat)/Iol or ....Diode Zt = ΔV/ΔI knee , same as LED.